# Integrating an exponential function on the hemisphere

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-geometry, contour-integration, bessel-functions

I want to calculate the first moment of an exponential function on a hemisphere. The function itself is of the very simple form
$$
f(\hat{\omega}) = \exp(\vec{v}\cdot\hat{\omega}),
$$
where $\hat{\omega}$ is a unit vector on the (hemi)sphere and $\vec{v}$ is some arbitrary vector. The integral I want to calculate is
$$
\int_{\Omega^+} (\hat{z}\cdot\hat{\omega}) \ f(\hat{\omega}) \,\mathrm{d}^2\hat{\omega}
= \int_{\Omega^+} (\hat{z}\cdot\hat{\omega}) \ \exp(\vec{v}\cdot\hat{\omega}) \,\mathrm{d}^2\hat{\omega},
$$
where $\Omega^+$ is the upper hemisphere (i.e. $\hat{z}\cdot\hat{\omega}\ge0$).
Writing this in standard spherical coordinates gives
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\mathrm{d}\theta
\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\phi\ 
\sin\theta\ \cos\theta\ \exp{(a\sin\theta \cos\phi + b\cos\theta)},
$$
where I chose the frame such that $\vec{v}=(a,0,b)$. This smells like some kind of Bessel contraption, but I can't quite seem to solve it. (Maybe with some funky contour integral magic?)

Comment: This might be a dumb idea but have you tried (before substituting) to write this as a volume integral using Gauß' Theorem?

Comment: Do you know this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769249/how-to-evaluate-int-02-pidx-int-0-pi-sin-ye-sin-y-cos-x-sin-x?

Comment: the $\phi$ integral can be brought in form, but i highely doubt if we get any further by this method

Comment: in form of a bessel function i  wanted to say

Comment: @user159517 : I hadn't thought of it yet, but it doesn't quite seem to help. If I want to integrate the volume integral in spherical coordinates, I end up with the same problem (with an additional $r$-integral over the radius). Trying to use Cartesian coordinates doesn't make it any less hairy. (And the bottom surface part where $z=0$ also needs to be accounted for as I only need the upper hemisphere itself.)

Comment: @tired : I looked at that post, but -- sadly -- in my case there is not a clearcut 1D (e.g. only $x$-) dependence when writing the integral in Cartesian coordinates

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}x \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \mathrm{d}y \exp\left(ax + b\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\right)
$$

(taking $\vec{v}=(a,0,b)$ like above).

For the spherical coordinates: I did find the Bessel relation in the $\phi$ integral, but the $\theta$ integral after that is indeed still a mess.

Comment: i got the same, so i would strongly assume there is no closed form

Comment: Would you possibly have any suggestion as far as approximations would go? (I sadly cannot assume anything about $a$ or $b$, they can be arbitrary large or small.)